# Add GROUP BY clause to crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report with a query that used to contain a client-id for each item.  The client (the boss) wanted multiple clients for each record.  That was easy - replace the client-id field with a new table ItemClients(item-id, client-id) and join on item-id.

The problem is now the reports - of course each item is duplicated for each time there is a client, BUT i WANT ONLY ONE COPY OF THE ITEM IN THE REPORT - irrespective of how many clients there are to an item.  Also, there is the ability to filter the report by client, which I can do fine in MySql and worked fine in the previous single-client version.

My solution is to add a group by item-id clause to the query (MySql allows this).  The problem is how to add the group by clause to the report.  Any attempt to group gets interpreted as a report grouping, which I don't want.  I tried to make the whole query as a command, which worked for a while, but now the whole report blows up, crashing my web server.

Any insights would be helpful.  thanks.

(edit)
Here's the (hybrid) code in the command, the GROUP BY clause was added by me, the rest was scraped from crystal's show sql command and modified.  (btw, this is a sub-report)

```
SELECT  `ITEM`.`Date`, `ITEM`.`Started`, `ITEM`.`Stopped`, `TERM`.`Terminal`, `ITEM`.`TonnesLoaded`, `ITEM`.`LoadID`, 
        `ITEM`.`TotalLoaded`, `ITEM`.`ToGo`, `ITEM`.`OrderId`, 
        `COM`.`Commodity`, 
        `berths1`.`Berth`, 
        `CQ`.`LotNo`, `CQ`.`CategoryID`, 
        `IC`.`ClientId`

FROM    `berths` `berths1`
INNER JOIN `Items` `ITEM` ON `berths1`.`BerthID`=`ITEM`.`BerthID`
INNER JOIN `terminals` `TERM` ON `berths1`.`TerminalID`=`TERM`.`TerminalID`
INNER JOIN `Quantities` `CQ` ON `ITEM`.`ItemId`=`CQ`.`ItemId`
    AND `ITEM`.`OrderId`=`CQ`.`OrderId`
INNER JOIN `commodities` `COM` ON `CQ`.`CommodityID`=`COM`.`CommodityID`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `ItemClients` `IC` ON `CQ`.`OrderId`=`IC`.`OrderId`
    AND `CQ`.`ItemId`=`IC`.`ItemId`
WHERE   `ITEM`.`OrderId`={?Pm-details.OrderId}
AND     ( {?Pm-?Category}=0 AND {?Pm-?ClientId}=0 ) 
OR      (
            `CQ`.CategoryID>0 
            AND `CQ`.CategoryID = {?Pm-?Category} 
            AND ( {?Pm-?ClientId}=0 OR IC.ClientId = {?Pm-?ClientId} ) 
        )
OR      ( {?Pm-?ClientId}>0 AND IC.ClientId = {?Pm-?ClientId} AND  {?Pm-?Category}=0 )

GROUP BY `ITEM`.`ItemId`
ORDER BY `ITEM`.`Date`, `ITEM`.`Started`, `ITEM`.`LoadID`
```

Comment: Can you post the query that you added in the command?

Comment: That's not possible at the moment - proprietary client data.  It will take me a while to sanitize it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. When you say you want one 'item' in the report, do you mean 1 item for the entire report, or you want the report grouped by item (i.e. only 1 section per item)?

Comment: if, for instance, there are 3 clients attached to an item, the query will return 3 rows for that item, due to the join.  I only want the item itself, not the info about the client.  I could also use "UNIQUE" in the query if crystal would allow that. (and not include client id or anything)

Comment: I have semi-resolved the problem by making two reports - one with client=0 (all), and the other with client=<n>.  Logic in the app decides which one to call.

Comment: I would also like to use GROUP_CONCAT() in my query, but crystal won't allow that without making a command